# After Save or Edit JqGrid doesn't refresh the records

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Im using JqGrid to list, add, delete, edit, find the my records. When i choose the loadonce=false, it normally refresh the records after del, edit or add. But, paging and searching mechanisim doesnt works. Once i choose the loadonce=true, it refresh the records after delete, not after add or edit. And then paging and searching runs normally in loadonce=true mode.  i tried the;

```
$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

or

```
afterInsertRow: function (rowid,rowdata,rowelem){
    alert("hello"); // this wasnt invoked
}
```

but they didnt solve my problem.

What's the reason my problem.

Comment: Which editing mode you use: form editing (for example buttons added by `navGrid`) or inline editing (for example buttons added by `inlineNav`)? It's two *absolutely different codes* of jqGrid which work different.

Comment: Im using navGrid not inline edit mode

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use `loadonce: false` than you have to implement paging, sorting and searching **on the server side**. If paging and searching are not working, then you don't implemented the features in your current server code.

The option `reloadAfterSubmit` specify whether the grid will be reloaded after editing.

If you use `loadonce: true` the `datatype` will be changed to `'local'` after the first load. The problem is that jqGrid don't support local form editing. So you have to implement the server part for Add/Edit/delete. The problem is that reloading  in the case will be executed **local** and not from the server. To reload the data from the server after end of form editing you can reset the `datatype` to the initial state ('json' or 'xml') inside of `afterSubmit` callback. In the case the next reloading (in case of `reloadAfterSubmit: true`) will be done from the server like you as want.

**UPDATED**: The following code of [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) should solve the problem:

```
afterSubmit: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
    return [true];
}
```

Comment: im using loadone:true and, i implemented delete,add and edit in server side. my only problem the after save or edit refreshing the page or grid list.i am anyway using reloadAfterSubmit:true, then i used to change local to json like this ; $("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid'); . then didnt reloaded the grid..

Comment: @RahmanUsta: Do you tried to set `$(this).setGridParam({datatype:'json'});` inside of `afterSubmit` callback of form editing like I recommended you in my answer?

Comment: i used like above ; jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('navGrid','#ptoolbar',{del:true,add:true,edit:true,search:true,refresh:true},{
  
  afterSubmit:function(){
      
     $(this).setGridParam({datatype:'json'});
  }
}); and didnt change

Comment: @RahmanUsta: Of cause you should return correct values from the `afterSubmit` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events)). The returned values for "Add" and "Edit" be different. In case of Edit operation you can use `afterSubmit:function(){ $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype:'json'}); return [true];}`. I think in case of `reloadAfterSubmit` one can return; `[true]` in case of Add operation too.

Comment: @RahmanUsta: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Ovilia1.htm). You will see that the data will be **reloaded from the server** (reseted to the initial state) after submitting. The demo use exactly the code which I posted and it works. The demo send first `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Ovilia.json?Name=Studen44&oper=edit&id=Student2` to the server as the "dummy" for Editing POST and then reload the data from the server.

Comment: You are incredible!! Cheers. Thanks a lot a lot a lot, Oleg.

Comment: The cause is, i defined the attributes like $.extend($.jgrid.del, { ...., i did changes inside this, it perfectly runs!!...

Comment: @RahmanUsta: My congratulations! It sounds as your problem are solved now. Is it so?

Comment: Try This Code; afterSubmit: function () {
                        location.reload(true);
                    }

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code;

```
afterSubmit: function () { location.reload(true); }
```