# jqGrid | add-edit-delete buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

sorry if my questions are simple , i'm totaly new to jqGrid :)

1- i want to use (add,edit,delete) feature of jqGrid , as you see there are buttons on the footer part of my grid but when i click just a dialog box comes and no fields to enter !! i want it just like [this page](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm)
[see my screen picture of what happens !](http://uploadax.com/images/12853732825088553833.png)

2- what happens when i click on submit button ( after fixing part 1 ) , i want to know how datas post to server!
no matter what language , i want to not for example they sent as object or sth , to know how to process them !

tnx alot

my source code  :

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index Page</title>
    <!-- external scripts -->

    <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.js" %}"/></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" %}"/></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css?id=1" %}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"/></script>
    <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap -->

    <!-- jqGrid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static "css/ui.jqgrid.css" %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{% static "css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css" %}" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/grid.locale-en.js" %}"/></script>
    <!-- jqGrid -->

    <!-- own implemented scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "js/script.js" %}"/></script>  
    <!-- own implemented scripts -->

    <!-- external scripts-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "http://localhost:8000/getdata",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "GET",
            colNames: ["شناسه", "کد","نام", "عنوان" ,"عنوان انگلیسی", "ظرفیت", "ظرفیت اضافه","قیمت روز"],
            colModel: [
                  { name: "id", index:"id", width: 60 , editable:true,editoptions: {readonly: "readonly"}},
            { name: "code", width: 60 , editable:true},
            { name: "name", width: 90 , editable:true},
            { name: "title", width: 90 ,editable:"true", editable:true},
            { name: "english_title", width: 100, align: "left", editable:true },
            { name: "capacity", width: 90, align: "left", editable:true },
            { name: "extra_capacity", width: 90, align: "left", editable:true },
            { name: "today_price", width: 80, align: "left" , editable:true},
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            pager: '#pager',
            loadonce:true,
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            gridview: true,
            multiselect: false,
            caption: "اتاق ها",
            onSelectRow: function(ids) {
                if(ids == null) {
                    ids=0;
                    if(jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') >0 )
                    {

                        jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"getpricelist?q=1&id="+ids,page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');

                    }
                } else {
                    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"getpricelist?q=1&id="+ids,page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid('setCaption',"لیست قیمت اتاق شماره : "+ids)
                }
            }
     });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false},
     /*   {
                    recreateForm: true,
                    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
                        $form.find(".FormElement[readonly]")
                            .prop("disabled", true)
                            .addClass("ui-state-disabled")
                            .closest(".DataTD")
                            .prev(".CaptionTD")
                            .prop("disabled", true)
                            .addClass("ui-state-disabled")
                    },
        }, */
     //edit options
       { // Edit option (parameters of editGridRow method)
        recreateForm:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        closeAfterEdit:true,
        url:'/edit',
        ajaxEditOptions: {
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                var csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
            }

        },
            afterSubmit: function () {
             jQuery("#list").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
             console.log('changed data type');
             return [true];
         },
        editData: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
        }
    },
    //add options
    { 
        recreateForm:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        url:'/add',
        ajaxEditOptions: {
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                var csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
            }
        },
            afterSubmit: function () {
             jQuery("#list").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
             console.log('changed data type');
             return [true];
         },
        editData: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
        }

    },
    //delete options
    { 
        recreateForm:true,
        reloadAfterSubmit:true,
        closeOnEscape:true,
        savekey: [true,13],
        url:'/delete',
        ajaxEditOptions: {
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                var csrf_token = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrf_token);
            }
        },
        afterSubmit: function () {
             jQuery("#list").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
             console.log('changed data type');
             return [true];
         },
        editData: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
        }
    }

    );
  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});
    jQuery("#list_d").jqGrid({
        height: 100,
    width:345,
        url:'getpricelist?q=1&id=2',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames:['از','تا', 'قیمت'],
        colModel:[

    {name:'from',index:'from', width:100},
    {name:'to',index:'to', width:100},
    {name:'price',index:'price', width:80, align:"right"},



        ],
        rowNum:5,
        rowList:[5,10,20],
        pager: '#pager_d',
        sortname: 'item',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: false,
        caption:"لیست قیمت"
    }).navGrid('#pager_d',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});

        }); 

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
        <div id="pager"></div> 

        <table id="list_d"></table>
        <div id="pager_d"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rooms.models import *
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core import serializers


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def getdata(request):
    data=room_type.objects.all()
    json=[]

    for o in data:
        json.append({'id':o.id, 'code':o.code,'name':o.name,'title':o.title, 
                     'english_title':o.english_title, 'capacity':o.capacity,
                     'extra_capacity':o.extra_capacity, 'today_price':o.today_price })

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(json), mimetype='application/json',content_type='application/json' )


def getpricelist(request):

    requested_room_id = request.GET.get('id', '')

    room = room_type.objects.get(id = requested_room_id)
    price_list_set = room.price_list_set.all()

    json=[]
    for price_list in price_list_set:
        json.append({'from':price_list.from_date, 'to':price_list.to_date, 'price':price_list.price})


    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(json), mimetype='application/json',content_type='application/json' )

def edit(request):
    print "################ediit#################"
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def add(request):
    print "################addddddddddd#################"
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def delete(request):
    print "################deeeeeeeeeeeeeel#################"
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Probably url:'/edit' etc URLs are wrong. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE or Google Chrome (press F12 to start) to trace HTTP traffic. Try url:'edit' or other relative path. The URL `"http://localhost:8000/getdata"` works but I recommend you to change it to *relative* path too: "getdata", "getdata/", "/getdata/" etc. I recommend you 1) to use the same option for Add as for Edit or to change default options of form editing on the page (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10287508/315935)). Currently you don't set options for Add and Delete

Comment: I recommend you additionally to use default `reloadAfterSubmit:true` and add reload the data inclusive the id of new added row from the server. You need still reset `datatype` to `"json"` inside of `afterSubmit` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11273416/315935)) to reload the data **from the server**. I recommend to move `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` after `grid.locale-en.js`.

Comment: no the urls are correct , i also updated my code to working version but 2 i have little problems :  
1- when i submit add form , the form doesn't go away and list doesn't refresh ! :( 
2-how can i **don't let users edit in edit form but add value in add form**(i want to do that for "today_price" col)  ! if i add **editoptions: {readonly: "readonly"}** changes in both edit and add forms and is not suitable for me !     

again thanks for saving my life :D   @Oleg

Comment: 1) you should use `closeAfterAdd: true` in the list of Add options 2) you placed `afterSubmit` on the wrong place. It's not callback of jqGrid - it's callback of form editing (see near `ajaxEditOptions`). 3) I suppose you should use `csrfmiddlewaretoken: function () { return getCookie('csrftoken');}` instead of `csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')`. 4) You can use `beforeShowForm` callback of form editing like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20498576/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6974432/315935) to disable some fields, set/remove readonly attribute etc...

Comment: thanks alot , but theres a problem with delete option ? whats wrong with delete part (3rd part) ?  i want to delete row but it seems its not working!
@Oleg

Comment: The "Delete" part of your code use wrong options. You should exactly examine [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2). You example you need use `ajaxDelOptions` instead of `ajaxEditOptions`, `delData` instead of `editData`, some other Edit option not exist for Delete etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is very easy to solve. The editing form (Add and Edit) includes only the information about **editable** columns. So you need include `editable: true` property in every column of `colModel` which you want to allow the user to edit.

It's important to understand that there are **default value** for every known property of `colModel`. I recommend you to examine the last ("Default") column of the table on [the place](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) of the documentation. You will find that default value of `align` is `"left"`, so you can remove `align: "left"` from all `colModel` items. In the same way you can see that default value of `editable` property is `false`. It way the reason why you had empty editing form. If you need to set `editable: true` to more as the half of columns of `colModel` I would recommend you to use `cmTemplate` option of jqGrid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935) for more details). After including `cmTemplate: {editable: true}` option for example you will need to include `editable: false` in all columns which you want don't make editable. All other columns will be editable.

If you need to include some column information in Add/Edit form, but don't permit the user to edit it you can use `editable: true` together with `editoptions: {readonly: "readonly"}` or `editoptions: {disabled: "disabled"}`. The option will include the information in the edit form, but set additional  `readonly="readonly"` or `disabled="disabled"` attribute on the corresponding editing field. One can add additional `"ui-state-disabled"` class on such filed like described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20498576/315935). In the way you can make some fields editable, but only for example in Add dialog and hold it disabled/readonly in Edit dialog. Don't forget to use `recreateForm: true` option.

To make editing successful it's very important to fill rowid of the grid correctly. If you have column with `name: "id"` or if some column have `key: true` property then the corresponding value will be used as rowid. The information which will be send to the server is described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server) (about Edit), [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server1) (about Add) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server2) (about Delele). The information contains always `id=rowidvalue` property. Add/Edit form post additionally information about all (inclusive hidden) editable columns in the form: `name=value`, where the `name` is the value of `name` property of the column definition in the `colModel`.

Comment: @ImanMirzadeh: Probably `url:'/edit'` etc URLs are wrong. Try `url:'edit'` or other relative path. The URL `"http://localhost:8000/getdata"` works but I recommend you to change it to *relative* path too `"getdata"`, `"getdata/"`, `"/getdata/"` etc. I recommend you 1) to use the same option for Add as for Edit or to change default options of form editing on the page (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10287508/315935)). Currently you **don't set options for Add and Delete**